# ¿Como puedo hacer que un dropdown se despliegue en una pagina aspx donde estoy importando un navbar?

Tags: html, asp.net, navbar, nav, dropdown

Quisiera saber como hacer que funcione un dropdown en una página .aspx en donde estoy importando un navbar de una pagina .html, el dropdown lo hice con bootstrap pero solo me funciona en la página .html, cuando intento correr la página .aspx me carga el botón que es un dropdown pero al seleccionarlo no se despliegan las opciones. Adjunto el código de la página .html:

```
<div class="dropdown show">
                <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Administrar Usuarios
                </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registrar Usuarios</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Gestionar Usuarios</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en la página .aspx:

```
<!--Navigation bar-->
<div id="nav-placehold">
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#nav-placehold").load("navbarAdmin.html");
    });
</script>
<!--end of Navigation bar-->
```